# Drawing 3D perpendicular rectangles in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, tikz-3d

Here is the picture I want to draw:

> [image]

I want to be able to change the yellow color also. also, not that the arrows are reversed on the grey rectangle Could someone help me in doing so please?

Comment: Care to share some foundational work that users can use to provide you with solutions?

Comment: @Werner I am sorry I will do this next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=20, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \fill [canvas is zx plane at y=0, gray] (-2, 0) rectangle (0, 3);
        \fill [yellow] (0, -1) rectangle (3, 1);
        \fill [canvas is zx plane at y=0, gray] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 3);
        
        \draw [canvas is zx plane at y=0, ->, thick] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) node [left] {\(b\)};
        \draw [canvas is zx plane at y=0, ->, thick] (2, 3) -- (-2, 3) node [right] {\(b\)};
        \draw [->, thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 1) node [above] {\(a\)};
        \draw [->, thick] (3, -1) -- (3, 1) node [above] {\(a\)};
        \draw [thick] (0, -1) -- ++ (0, 0.23);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To change the colour of the yellow plane simply change `yellow` to whatever colour you desire.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play with some opacity, here's a solution:

[image: Drawing 3D perpendicular rectangles in latex]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        plana/.style={pink,opacity=0.8},
        planb/.style={purple!50,opacity=0.8},
        arr/.style={-Stealth, line width=2pt}
        ]
        \def\L{6} \def\H{4} \def\S{1}
        \fill[plana] (0,0) rectangle (\L,-\H/2);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (0,-\H/2) -- (0,0);
        \fill[planb] (-\S,-\S) --++ (\L,0) --++ (2*\S,2*\S) --++ (-\L,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[arr] (\S,\S) --++ (-2*\S,-2*\S) node [pos=1.1] {$b$};
        \fill[plana] (0,0) rectangle (\L,\H/2);
        \draw[arr] (-\S+\L,-\S) --++ (2*\S,2*\S) node [pos=1.1] {$b$};
        \draw[arr] (\L,-\H/2) --++ (0,\H) node [pos=1.1] {$a$};
        \draw[arr] (0,0) --++ (0,\H/2) node [pos=1.2] {$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing!! thank you